# ExecuteScalar connection property has not not been initialized

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

When I run this piece of code I get the error:

> ExecuteScalar connection property has not not been initialized

I can't seem to find why the connection isn't working.

Code:

```
Protected Sub btnTrackRepair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTrackRepair.Click

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ITrepair.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(conn.ToString)
        Dim txtTracking As String
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Repair_Status FROM Repair WHERE Tracking_Number =" & txtTrack.Text
        txtTracking = If(IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar), "", cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        If txtTracking <> "" Then
            MsgBox("Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
            txtStatus.Text = ""
            txtStatus.Text = txtTracking
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFO.")
        End If
    End Using

End Sub
```

The code breaks at `txtTracking = If(IsDBNull(cmd.ExecuteScalar), "", cmd.ExecuteScalar)`

I have looked at other questions regarding this error however most are C# and I'm using VB.NET so I have found it difficult to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the [`SqlCommand` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sebfsz50(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes only a string. But this is not the connection-string but the text of the query. So you've done it wrong.

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Repair_Status FROM Repair WHERE Tracking_Number = @Tracking_Number", conn)
```

Apart from that you should really get familiar with parameterized queries. Don't use string concatenation to build your queries to avoid (among other issues) sql-injection attacks.

Here is the complete method:

```
Protected Sub btnTrackRepair_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sqlQuery = "SELECT Repair_Status FROM Repair WHERE Tracking_Number = @Tracking_Number"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ITrepair.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Tracking_Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtTrack.Text

        Dim statusObj = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Dim status = If(statusObj is DBNull.Value, Nothing, DirectCast(statusObj, string))

        If not String.IsNullOrEmpty(status) Then
            MsgBox("Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update")
            ' ... '
        Else
            MsgBox("No Record Found!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "INFO.")
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

If the `Tracking_Number` is not a varchar/nvarchar but an `int`(for example) in the database, you should parse it already here and use the correct `SqlDbType`.

Comment: ok thank you, so what do i do with this part of the code then? // cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Repair_Status FROM Repair WHERE Tracking_Number =" & txtTrack.Text) //

Comment: @CormacD: i have edited my answer. That code is redundant

Comment: @CormacD - or create command with `Using command = connection.CreateCommand()` but then you need to assign query to `command.CommandText`

Comment: @TimSchmelter tried your method and just edited the SqlDbType to data.SqlDbType.Int to suit Tracking_Number and edited '...' to txtStatus.Text = ""
txtStatus.Text = status to catch my output but once i run the code and click the TrackRepair button i don't get anything back the page just seems to refresh